# How to manually insert outliers in the dummy dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, insert, outliers

I have created a dummy dataset with this below code :

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()


def make_workers() -> list:
    status_list = ['in', 'out']
    room_list = ['FL1_RM1', 'FL1_RM2', 'FL1_RM3', 'FL1_RM4', 'FL2_RM1', 'FL2_RM2', 'FL2_RM3', 'FL2_RM4', 'FL3_RM1',
                 'FL3_RM2', 'FL3_RM3', 'FL3_RM4', 'FL4_RM1', 'FL4_RM2', 'FL4_RM3', 'FL4_RM4']
    Property = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']
    d1 = datetime.strptime('03/01/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')
    d2 = datetime.strptime('08/08/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')
    timestamps = pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq="1min")
    return [{**elem, **{"Floor_Number": elem.get("room_id")[2]}} for elem in [
        {'ID'          : fake.random_number(digits=6),
         'Property num': np.random.choice(Property, p=[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]),
         'room_id'     : np.random.choice(room_list),
         'Temp'        : np.random.randint(low=35, high=50),
         'noted Date'  : timestamps[x],
         'Status'      : np.random.choice(status_list),
         'Humidity'    : np.random.uniform(low=-35.09, high=70.00),
         'Dust'        : np.random.randint(low=2, high=5),
         'CO2 level'   : np.random.uniform(low=350.09, high=450.00)
         } for x in range(len(timestamps))]]


worker_df = pd.DataFrame(make_workers())
worker_df.head(30)
```

the sample of the dataset has been shown in the pic below, now I want to insert some outliers for columns Temp and Humidity where its value would not be in the specified range in the code , for example : for Temp column, as per my initial specs can take only values in the range 35 to 50, now the outliers should have values >50 or <35 and same idea goes for humidity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? `d_min`, `d_max` and `mutate_chance` can be set arbitrarily to get whatever date looks good for what you're doing. Inserting random values may be quicker as it could avoid `apply` (which can be slow for large datasets) but it ran in 0.4s for me with your dataset.

```py
def mutate(n, d_min, d_max, mutate_chance=0.05, round=True):
  r = np.random.random()
  d = d_min + np.random.random() * (d_max - d_min)
  if r < mutate_chance / 2:
    # mutate high
    return int(n + d) if round else n + d
  elif r < mutate_chance:
    # mutate low
    return int(n - d) if round else n - d
  
  return n

oldTemp = worker_df['Temp']
oldHumidity = worker_df['Humidity']
worker_df['Temp'] = oldTemp.apply(lambda n: mutate(n, 20, 30))
worker_df['Humidity'] = oldHumidity.apply(lambda n: mutate(n, 34, 72, round=False))
```

Now if we run

```py
print((oldTemp == worker_df['Temp']).value_counts())
```

we will get a table showing how many values have stayed the same (`True`) or changed (`False`). When I ran it I had 11419 become outliers and 218982 remained the same.

To see specifically which ones have changed we can do

```py
print(oldTemp[oldTemp != worker_df['Temp']])
print(worker_df['Temp'][oldTemp != worker_df['Temp']])
```

Comment: as there is no change (no outlier values are introduced in some of the rows of the specified columns) in the result when i give "mutate_chance = 0.05" , i tried giving "mutate_chance = 2.0" but the result is many values in rows ( Temp and humidity) are turning are into outliers, and its almost as if we are randomly creating a column with a certain range. for example i generally wanted the Temp column value to be values ranging from 35 to 50, and expected to have some/few outliers whose values exceed this range. but now it is normally changing the whole column values to a new range.

Comment: `mutate_chance` is meant to be [0..1] and represents the decimal chance (i.e. 0.05 = 5%) a given row becomes (through changing its temp and humidity values) an outlier row. Having it be greater than 1 means you *will* be changing every row. While it may not seem like it is not changing much, it does change. However, I haven't actually updated the dataframe as `apply` is not in-place. I will edit the answer to show this and also to show how I verified it.